# pandas combine line and point plot

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I want to plot pandas timeseries data in a line and combine it with point data in one plot. (I have daily values over a full year and values at some specific dates that should be plotted as points.)

Is there a possibility to plot the point data only as markers without a line? I tried it with `style = 'x'` but the legend is empty where the style should be.

[image]

And when I use `marker = 'o'` there is always a line between the points.

[image]

`df_points`

```
            point_values
2015-10-31     34.000000
2015-11-30     86.914286
2015-12-14    109.777778
2015-12-29    113.340206
2016-01-13    239.503817
2016-01-19    296.768657
2016-01-27    296.849558
2016-02-02    377.489726
2016-02-10    436.665698
2016-02-24    506.214689
2016-03-02    523.585106
2016-03-15    574.376344
2016-04-01    602.537143
2016-04-15    662.771812
2016-04-29    738.079096
2016-05-15    784.083333
2016-05-31    698.914286
2016-06-14    539.915254
2016-06-29    318.356164
```

`df_lines`

```
        line_values
2015-10-31    34.010000
2015-11-30    97.800000
2015-12-14   127.700000
2015-12-29   147.000000
2016-01-13   252.150000
2016-01-19   329.900000
2016-01-27   341.700000
2016-02-02   389.700000
2016-02-10   478.550000
2016-02-24   543.300000
2016-03-02   562.700000
2016-03-15   620.100000
2016-04-01   636.500000
2016-04-15   628.482486
2016-04-29   708.000000
2016-05-15   770.000000
2016-05-31   808.000000
2016-06-14   632.900000
2016-06-29   415.528680


fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(12, 10))
df_points['point_values'].plot(ax=ax1, label='point values', legend=True,        grid=True, sharex=True, style = 'o')
df_lines['line_values'].plot(ax=ax1, label='daily values', legend=True, grid=True, sharex=True)
```

Comment: You can plot a `scatter plot` for `df_points` on the same axis with the `line plot` for `df_lines`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I switch the order of the plot command, the label in the legend appears.
[image: plot with label]

```
fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(12, 10))
df_lines['line_values'].plot(ax=ax1, label='daily values', legend=True, grid=True, sharex=True)
df_points['point_values'].plot(ax=ax1, label='point values', legend=True, grid=True, style = 'o')
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: This should have been a comment. After all it was your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can plot a scatter plot on top of the line plot to achieve this. Refer to below code.

If the `dates` are the `index` in both the dataframes,

```
df_lines.index = [pd.to_datetime(d) for d in df_lines.index]
df_points.index = [pd.to_datetime(d) for d in df_points.index]
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(12, 10))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.scatter(x=df_points.index, y=df_points['point_values'] ,label='point values')
df_lines.plot(ax=ax1, label='line values', color='darkorange')
ax1.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]